# Override toString() for an Android activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, overriding, tostring

After running *Inspect Code* from the *Analyze* menu of the Android Studio (after customizing the inspection profile), I get this warning:

*ID:* ClassHasNoToStringMethod

*Description:* Reports classes without toString() method.

*Problem synopsis:* Class 'MainActivity' does not override 'toString()' method (at line 30)

Note: line 30 holds the declaration of the MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
```

This is only reported for the Main Activity, that extends Activity. I also have an activity that extends  PreferenceActivity, but no toString warning is reported for it.

**1.** Does it make sense to override 'toString()' for an activity, as suggested? In what cases would it help? Is it a best practice?

**2.** How would an Activity toString override implementation look like?

**3.** Why isn't the warning reported for the PreferenceActivity descendant?

Comment: I wonder what's at MainActivity:30. (*whistles*)

Comment: Post your whole activity code. You're doing something wrong as that error shouldn't come up.